# Set Azure Metadata on BlockBlob via REST API

Tags: javascript, rest, azure

I want to set some custom metadata property on a Blob on Azure using the Azure REST API.
The upload of the file works ok (also done via REST API). To set my custom metadata I followed [these instructions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd179414.aspx). A sample URL could be:

(PUT Method)
https://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/ph0wzj1k4dbuwfusyqw38z2jgfk5p56bfnlj5/a5bc77a8d4d34edeb6d3212fc6bbd8a9.jpg?sv=2014-02-14&sr=c&si=BlobContainer&sig=someSignaturecomp=metadata

with this request header:

x-ms-meta-logicalname:20141028_064011.jpg

Whether I run this url via jquery ajax or thru Fiddler I always get the same result: the call seems to be successful (I get a 200 status code) but if then I inspect the blob metadata (using C# code) the key is not found and the metadata is empty.

Instead, if I do everything with C#, I can set and get any metadata on my blob as I wish.

Sample C# code (now working):

```
var blobs = container.ListBlobs(null, true, BlobListingDetails.Metadata).Cast<CloudBlockBlob>();
foreach (var blob in blobs) {
    Console.WriteLine(blob.Metadata["logicalname"]);
}
```

As you can see I have entered my shared access signature in the url and not in the request headers as the instructions show, but I doubt that is the problem because on uploading and other operations (also on table storage) everything works fine.

Am I doing something wrong? (obviously yes, but what?... :) )

**SOLVED:**

Investigating with Azure Storage Explorer I saw that the metadata is correctly set and is there, it was just not retrieved via C#. Thanx to Gaurav's suggestion I have edited the C# code sample I had posted and am now retrieving the metadata that I had set via REST API.

Comment: Can you share the code for fetching the blob's metadata through C#?

Comment: edited the post with C# sample

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The metadata is there but you're not able to see it because you haven't fetched it. What you could do is change the `ListBlobs()` call. Assuming you're using the latest version of storage client library, you can do something like:

```
var blobs = container.ListBlobs(null, true, BlobListingDetails.Metadata).Cast<CloudBlockBlob>();
```

This will populate the metadata along with other properties.

Comment: I have again edited my post. I investigated with azure storage explorer and the value is actually there but even with your approach the metadata retrieved by C# is still empty. At least now I know the value is set and I will keep investigating. Of course if u have other suggestions they are welcome :)

Comment: ok solved there was no longer the need to perfogm GetBlockBlobReference to get the metadata. I have edited my C# sample code accordingly